# Let's get critical: Oct 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Windows Phone Stack Exchange](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How can I get Cortana to change a reminder time using voice commands?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/5532/how-can-i-get-cortana-to-change-a-reminder-time-using-voice-commands)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Upgrading phone, keep XBox Music Pass on old phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/5503/upgrading-phone-keep-xbox-music-pass-on-old-phone)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How can I know the version of an installed app?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/how-can-i-know-the-version-of-an-installed-app)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Text suggestion, word flow not working](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/5555/text-suggestion-word-flow-not-working)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to create an App Corner?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/5466/how-to-create-an-app-corner)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How to update to Windows Phone 8.1 update 1?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/5465/how-to-update-to-windows-phone-8-1-update-1)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Transfer contacts/messages from bada](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/5508/transfer-contacts-messages-from-bada)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [How can I really delete e-mail in my Gmail account?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/5483/how-can-i-really-delete-e-mail-in-my-gmail-account)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [What is the size of Windows Phone 8.1 update?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/5586/what-is-the-size-of-windows-phone-8-1-update)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 7)

---

- [Message Tone is not working](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/5561/message-tone-is-not-working)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately we (as all SE sites) have a lot of Abandoned questions by their OP.

Some even receive some attention and even a correct answer but the OP never returned to accept it.

Comment: Or comments asking for more detail, that never get answered...